# how to enable trust access to the vba project object model programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, excel

[image]How to enable trust access to the vba project object model programmatically in C#

I could change it manually and get the work done.

```
gobjExcel =    Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application"));
            objWorkbooks = gobjExcel.Workbooks;
            objWorkbook = objWorkbooks.Open(fileName);              
            Type thisType = objWorkbook.GetType();
            dynamic objProj = objWorkbook.VBProject;
```

Comment: Try recording a macro when you enable it and see if the macro contains steps for it.

Comment: There is no legitimate use for programmatically enabling that setting other that writing malware. If you are in a corporate environment where you want this setting on (which is not wise), use [group policy](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49030) to push it to computers.

Comment: We need it in few excel files where we need to add some macros. It is legitimate only. We don't want the user to manually find those settings.

Answer (score 1):

Update the below registry key,,

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Security\AccessVBOM